# Does sql query use 2nd level hibernate cache in place of hql.?

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, ehcache, hibernate-cache

Basically I don't have knowledge about it, I just want to clear my doubt. That when we use sql in place hql through hibernate API, will it use 2nd level cache before making query in database.? The reason being I want to utilise my 2nd level cache as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not, because Hibernate cannot track what you fetch in the native query.

HQL will also not utilize it **before** query execution, but **after** it, when it starts assembling the entities from the result set.